# Updating MongoDB array from variable array in batch operation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am working in Node.js and am attempting to push or pull the contents of an array to my mongodb collection. Currently my [working] code to pull objects from the array in FieldArray looks something like this:

```
for (var i=0; i < MyList.length; i++) {
    collection.update(
        {field:"MyValue"},
        {$pull: {FieldArray: MyList[i]}},
        function(err, item){...}
    );
}
```

I'm aware of the ability to use $push/$each, $addToSet/$each and $pullall but they don't seem to accept values dynamically from an array (or I haven't found any indication that it can). Basically, I'd like to be able to use this function with an array of one item or one hundred, using the appropriate batch calls.

Is there any way to make such a call without having to loop through a separate call on the database for each iteration?

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic array? For your case `{$push: {FieldArray: {$each: MyList}}}` would work perfectly. You don't need to iterate over the array.

Comment: Dynamic in terms of size such that I can't always specificy something like MyList[1] or MyList[5] since it may not exist. If what you're saying is true (and I have no doubt it is) then I Must have been doing something wrong when I tried that, or thought I tried it. Will try again and report back, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [$pullAll](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/#up._S_pullAll). It does exactly what you are trying to iterate over

```js
collection.update(
    { "field": "MyValue" },
    { "$pullAll": { "FieldArray": MyList } }
)
```

If that doesn't work then then your array elements are not matching the structure used in your document. Make them that way.

Comment: It's late at night and I'm tired, but I'm totally befuddled by the name "pull".  Why isn't it called "removeFromArray" or perhaps, if you want to be consistent with JavaScript, "splice"?  In 30+ years of programming I've never heard "pull" used for "remove elements from an array".  And a quickie Google search agrees with me.

Comment: @user949300 No idea. $pull matches one element and removes, $pullAll matches the specified elements in a list. No real equiv of slice or splice. But $push and $pop are there. The operators just do different things.

Comment: Ok, looks like I was on the right track and close, but must have done something wrong, I tried it again and it's working great with $pullAll and $push/$each. Thanks!